# AS3 - Communicating between timers and loops

Tags: actionscript-3, class, loops, timer

I have two classes, one with a loop and one with a timer and I am trying to send data from the timer to the loop.

Here is the relevant part of Main.as:

```
var zero:int = 0;
var shoot:Shooting = new Shooting(zero); //send zero to class Shooting
while (shoot.finished == 0)  
{    
  move.data; //here data to move an object, rest is irrelevant...
}
```

Relevant from class Shooting.as:

```
public class Shooting extends Sprite
{
private var twenty:int;
private var remove:int;
public  var _isPassed:int = 0;
private var thedata:int;
public var finished:int = 0;

    public function Shooting(data:int):void
    {
    thedata = data; // store the zero
    var updateTimer:Timer;
    updateTimer = new Timer(1, 30); 
    updateTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, Fire);
    updateTimer.start();    
    }

        public function Fire(e:TimerEvent):void                                                         
        {
        for(var i:int=thedata; i >= 0; i--){ // data is bigger or = to 0 so keep going
        if (_isPassed == 29)
        {       
        finished = 1;
        _isPassed = 0; 
        //do more stuff and break
        break; 
        }           
           // it will go here if it's not the 29 time and do +1 to ispassed.
            _isPassed += 1; 
            var atwenty:int = 20;
            twenty = atwenty;


            break;
        }   
}
```

So, in Main.class there's a "while" that checks if finished == 0(by default it is), if so it will move an object. In Shooting.as, there's a timer going on
30 times and in the 29th time it is supposed to stop itself(which it does), and change the var finished to 1. problem is, while does not detect that "1" and it keeps moving that object and my flash crashes. I am looking for a better way to communicate between timers and classes, and also figure out what I did wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: you don't understand what a while loop is doing and how it works. I suggest you forget about using while loop for now. If you want a clue here it is: No code anywhere in the app can run or execute while a while loop is running. Nothing can be updated on screen, no timer can run, no enterframe can run, no code as small as possible can run while a while loop is running.

Comment: Thanks for your input mate, do you have an alternative way to check once finished == 1? I thought loop is just always running in the background.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, are you trying to fire a bullet? If so all you need is an enterframe event to start with.

Comment: Yeah I was actually checking other ways other than enterframe event, in order to make everything in one place and more cleaner. nevermind.

Comment: Using enterframe doesn't mean you have to create bunch of them. You can create just one and run everything with it.